# How to add prop type validation with useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am using useMemo to help me create a table. I am getting prop-type errors on the Cell property.

```
        () => [
            {
                Header: "Action",
                id: "linkTo", 
                accessor: "id",
                Cell: props => <ViewButton id={props.value}/>
            }
        ],
        []
    );
```

`'value' is missing in props validation`

Comment: Can you please provide your entire code? Are you using `prop-types`, if yes then have you declared `value` as a prop too? Can you please check?